# Different 'Items Per Page' on different pagination while using 'views_infinite_scroll' module

Tags: 8, views, ajax, paging

I am using [views_infinite_scroll](http://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) module to load more nodes with 10 nodes on every click and views AJAX is enabled.

I am working on a requirement like as, I have 100 total nodes and getting in a view page. On first load, I need to show 3 nodes and on load more load next 10 nodes.

```
  if(!$view->getPager()->getCurrentPage()){
    $view->setItemsPerPage(3);
  }
```

I know above code should work in such case. But the **`problem`** is "next page doesn't include 4-10 nodes while it will show nodes from 11-20 (next 10 nodes). I need to load ignored 7 nodes (4-10) should also appears on next page (?page=1) along with next 3 nodes (11-13).

I have tried `hook_views_pre_render`, `hook_views_post_render`, `hook_views_pre_build`, `hook_views_post_build`, `hook_views_query_alter` etc. but no success to load ignored nodes on next page (?page=1) while load more using AJAX.

Any kind of help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want the remaining part of first page ( 7 items) will be dropped from the result?

Comment: Yes, I need such 7 items to show on next page along with 3 items (10 ItemsPerPage).

Comment: don't waste your time on the handle it with Drupal side. 
I suggest handling it by the FE side, Jquery will be a good candidate.

Comment: Any suggestion with jQuery? Really appreciate that as I have already wasted much time on that,

Comment: I suggest a solution as an answer. check it and let me know if you need more details and help. I'm here to help drupalist ;)

Comment: Does this work how you'd like it to with other pagers?

Comment: Looks like there's an [open issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll/issues/2852080) with a patch to add this functionality on d.o.